# Julia: create a package with optional dependencies

Tags: dependencies, package, julia

I want to build a numerical package that also has optional support for visualization. For simplicity, let's say the respective dependencies are `NumPackage` for the heavy lifting
 and `VizPackage` for optional visualization.

In Julia, how can I build a module that has `NumPackage` in its **required** dependencies, but `VizPackage` only as an **optional** dependency, say for example for those users that want to run an example simulation and visualize it?

I saw the [Requires.jl](https://github.com/MikeInnes/Requires.jl) package but not sure if it's the right tool for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: There's a [discussion on Github](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/1285) about this. Apparently, Requires.jl is the current standard, but I've never used it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current best solution (2019-10-04) is to use [`Requires.jl`](https://github.com/MikeInnes/Requires.jl). However, there are a number of issues with `Requires.jl` so there are plans for a better solution, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/1285. Hopefully it will be ready in time for Julia version 1.4 or 1.5.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to add optional dependencies to a package, but for the specific case of having a dependency on a visualization package, what you can do is create [plot recipes](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/recipes/). In order to have plot recipes in your package, you only need to depend on [RecipesBase.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/RecipesBase.jl), which is a very minimal package. If you create plot recipes for your types you will then be able to use [Plots.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl) to visualize the information contained in your types, without having an explicit dependency on Plots.jl in your package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am sure it can be a good solution in many scenarios. In my particular case, I used "visualization" to refer to all kinds of packages from simple plotting all the way to GUI components.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in some cases needed a dependency on PyPlot because the needed functionality is not there in Plots. OTOH Plots/gr is faster, so in cases where it is sufficient it makes sense to use that one.

I figured out that you can just pass the plot module as an additional parameter to a plotting function and as an optional parameter to a numerical example. You also can have heuristics to distinguish between different plot modules.  See e.g. [here](https://github.com/j-fu/VoronoiFVM.jl/blob/master/src/vfvm_plot.jl) (I plan to modify this and to add a type annotation Plotter::Union{Module,Nothing}).

So a user would run your package e.g. as follows:

Without plotting:

```
using NumPackage

NumPackage.run()
```

With plotting:

```
using NumPackage
using VizPackage

NumPackage.run(Plotter=VizPackage)
```

There needs to be no mentioning at all of VizPackage in Project.toml.

Testing and code coverage is another question though...

Jürgen